# Will a USB Bluetooth 5.0 adapter help with wireless issues?

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Toshiba laptop Satellite L70D
CPU: AMD a10-5750 Quad Core @2.5Ghz
RAM: 8GB

I'm having an issue with the wireless internet connection when I use Bluetooth. The symptoms are - the internet won't load pages or does so extremely slowly. If I switch bluetooth off, it's fine. I am lead to believe that my wireless connection and the bluetooth system use the same radio frequencies and sometimes interfere.

Would using an external USB Bluetooth 5.0 adapter (dongle) help?

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 list

```
grep: list: No such file or directory
```

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0612]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: They will still use the same frequencies if you are uisng 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 list` terminal command.

Comment: That was a typo. Run this `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`